# How do I make sure a decimal is always displayed as xxxx.xxxx positive and negative?

Tags: c#

I have a decimal on an object in C#. I want to be able to display it as xxxx.xxxx at the moment the value is -1.61769, basically I want to round the last two digits up and make sure that it only ever has 4 decimal places after the decimal place. Im not sure if this is a Math operation (i.e. Math.Round) or is a validation operation (i.e. string.Format) or both?..

Hope someone can help...

Comment: How should -1.61769 look in your "xxxx.xxxx" format? -0001.6177?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string result = d.ToString("0.0000");
```

You may also want to specify a culture:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string result = d.ToString("0.0000", cultureInfo);
```

Result:

```
-1.6177
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/MxJii)

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ Gives some great examples as well on other waits of formatting.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether you want *at most* four decimal places, or *exacty* four decimal places.

If you round the value, you get at most four decimal places:

```
value = Math.Round(value, 4);
```

The value `1.61799` for example would be rounded to `1.6180` and display as `1.618`.

If you format the value, you get exactly four decimal places:

```
string formatted = value.ToString("0.0000");
```

Comment: Actually, calling `Math.Round(value, 4).ToString()` will give exactly four decimals. `1.61799m` would be rounded to `1.6180m` and displayed as "1.6180" (or "1,6180", or perhaps something else, depending on the culture). I think you're thinking of doubles, but this question is about decimals.

Comment: @hvd: Good point, however it's not certain whether the op means a `Decimal` type value or just a decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check with string.Format if you are looking to have a string.

check that link [c# double format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

if you are looking for keeping the value of the number you should use Math.round

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `Math.Abs()`?
According to this [MSDN-Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it is not possible.
Because it would display a diffierent Value.

`Math.Abs(-1.61769).ToString("####.####");`

Comment: This does not do what the author wants.  He wants to round the value not do the absolute value of it which would get ride of the negative positive sign.

Comment: @Ramhound The question asks for "always displayed as xxxx.xxxx positive and negative" -- if x represents a digit, then there is nowhere in xxxx.xxxx to put the sign. I think you're right that this is not what the author meant to ask, but that's no reason for downvoting an answer that merely assumes the question is correct.